# How can I stop custom post type redirecting to blog archive page?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

How can I stop custom post type redirecting to blog archive page?  Or can we create a separate page for custom post types display?

Creating custom post type for Exhibits:

```
add_action('init','exhibits_custom_init');
function exhibits_custom_init(){

    $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Exhibits', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Exhibit', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'exhibit'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Exhibit'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Exhibit'),
    'new_item' => __('New Exhibit'),
    'view_item' => __('View Exhibit'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Exhibits'),
    'not_found' => __('No Exhibits Found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Exhibits Found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' =>  '',
    'menu_name' => 'Exhibits'
    ); 

    $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_in_menu' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'exhibit'),
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'has_archive' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => null,
    'supports' => array('title','thumbnail','editor'),
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag','post_category')   

    );
    register_post_type('exhibit',$args);
}

function my_taxonomies_exhibit(){
    $labels = array(
            'name'              => _x( 'Exhibit Categories', 'taxonomy general name' ),

        'singular_name'     => _x( 'Exhibit Category', 'taxonomy singular name' ),

        'search_items'      => __( 'Search Exhibit Categories' ),

        'all_items'         => __( 'All Exhibit Categories' ),

        'parent_item'       => __( 'Parent Exhibit Category' ),

        'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Exhibit Category:' ),

        'edit_item'         => __( 'Edit Exhibit Category' ), 

        'update_item'       => __( 'Update Exhibit Category' ),

        'add_new_item'      => __( 'Add New Exhibit Category' ),

        'new_item_name'     => __( 'New Exhibit Category' ),

        'menu_name'         => __( 'Exhibit Categories' ),

    );

    $args = array(

        'labels' => $labels,
        'hierarchical' => true,
    );

    register_taxonomy( 'post_category', 'exhibit', $args );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_taxonomies_exhibit', 0 );
```

This custom post type redirecting to blog archive page.  I want to display it in the content page or a separate page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know If I understand your question 100%. If you need a dedicated template file for your CPT: Exhibits, duplicate single.php rename: single-exhibits.php and WP should use that template file for the Exhibits CPT.

Might be that you need to re-save your permalink structure, check that first.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display

Comment: yes you are correct. but for the list of posts it is showing from archive.php instead of content-page.php(i am using 2011 theme)

Comment: strange, it is working for me: http://develop.cpp.nl/exhibit/test/

I pasted your stuff in 2011 functions.php, made a single-exhibit.php re-saved the permalinks and hit view on the test exhibit and there is is.

Comment: Look at this URL http://develop.cpp.nl/exhibit/ your posts are displaying in archive page. But i don't want to display that in archive page.

Comment: aaah... well you could make a archive-exhibit.php and adjust it

http://develop.cpp.nl/exhibit/

Comment: Hoo..Thank you..working..So any page we can duplicate and use it?

Comment: not all, page-exhibit.php doesn't work due it is a diferent kind of post type. check http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Custom_Post_Types_display if it's possible. And: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: if i make it exhibits.php?

Comment: Could be, don't think so: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Template_Files If you want, you could rewrite stuff via htaccess, but that's not something I'm very good at.